# Reload a Tableau custom SQL DataSource (live) with a parameter = username() after a logout and login with a different user

Tags: tableau-api

I created a DataSource like this:

```
select sd.* from global_reporting.summary_drivers sd
join global_reporting.vw_row_level_security vrls
on vrls.company = sd.company
where vrls.company = SUBSTRING_INDEX(<Parameters.COMPANY_AND_USER>, '~~', 1)
and
vrls.username = SUBSTRING_INDEX(<Parameters.COMPANY_AND_USER>, '~~', -1)
```

The problem is that if I logout and log back in from a WebApplication that includes the dashboard into an iframe, the username() function changes correctly but the derived parameter does not change and so also the DataSource remains with the old data.

Parameters.COMPANY_AND_USER was set starting from a calculated field, from the username() function.

Questions:

- Am I on the right path or is there a better or any other way to do that?

Comment: Read about user filters in the Tableau documentation

Comment: Yes, we are using that approach now. But we have a large number of users (we don't want to map manually) and a large number of rows to filter, and we were trying a more direct approach at DataSource level, also to load less data from the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are embedding your views in a web page, you can use the JavaScript API to fine tune how your view behaves or more tightly couple it with your web page
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm

For instance, you could tell your views to refresh data using the RefreshDataASync() function whenever the user changes.

I’d recommend using the `<object>` tag placed inside a `<div>` instead of the `<iframe>` tag for embedding your views, to get a bit more control.
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_code.htm

Tableau produced a very good quick tutorial about their JavaScript API that lets you get a very good idea of what it provides and how to use it that you can skim in about 5 minuets. Highly recommended. https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm

All that said, you absolutely can use custom SQL for your data source, but I’d drop to that level only if you’re convinced the higher level features won’t work for you. If only for maintainability reasons.

Comment: @mario-stefanutti - check the edited answer, references to HTML tags were not visible originally, now fixed